# Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on a POCO

Tags: c#, .net, poco

I have a POCO class with a number of properties that can be get/set.

Does implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on this class violate the principles of a POCO?

I would like another class to be notified of any changes to the POCO and write these changes to a file, and having it listen for a property changed seems like the best way of doing this

Comment: Do you follow MVVM? If so, use ViewModel for that.

Comment: `INotifyPropertyChanged` is not tightly related to MVVM.

Comment: @FCin `INotifyPropertyChanged` is part of `System.ComponentModel` and there is absolutely no reason why any object can not utilise it including classes to be used in or around WPF; EF or WCF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as it fulfills your requirement AND you know what you are doing, there is no problem.

In software world, people generally face same problem redundantly. To handle these problems in consistent and tested/verified way, patterns/paradigms were introduced. All patterns/paradigms generally lay down the guidelines. Most of them (few does though) do not state how those should be implemented.

That said, it is up to the developer who is implementing the pattern decide the implementation details. Make sure you do not create new problem through your implementation.

Term POCO is derived from its Java equivalent POJO. Following is what Martin Fowler [says](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/POJO.html) about POJO:

> In the talk we were pointing out the many benefits of encoding business logic into regular java objects rather than using Entity Beans. We wondered why people were so against using regular objects in their systems and concluded that it was because **simple objects lacked a fancy name. So we gave them one, and it's caught on very nicely.**

Notice the **bold** text in above quote.

Considering this, implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` on POCO class should not be considered a violation the POCO principles.

About `INotifyPropertyChanged` and MVVM relation: The interface is defined in `System.ComponentModel` and is NOT tightly bound to MVVM.

Comment: _"...it was because simple objects lacked a fancy name"_ - I wonder if that lead to _"DTOs"_ as well? :)

Comment: I (personally) do not see any fundamental difference between POCO and DTO other than the PURPOSE those are used for. There might be implementation differences due to the context they are being used in.

Answer (score 1):

You need one way or another to notify your application of changes in the database (provided there's more than one instance at a time).

Making your POCOs implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` is a legimate way to do so. Note that it resides in the `System.ComponentModel` namespace and - although used widely in WPF - is not a ui-thing.

An alternative could by some CQRS-scheme that notifies your POCO-consuming services of changes via specifically designed interfaces.